# Responsive tables in bootstrap 3 joins when resolution in below 768px

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, html-table

I have a page in which I am using multiple table; `ng-repeat` directive. Below is the html code which I am having in my web-page.

```
<table class="table table-bordered" ng-repeat="item in jsonArray">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Title</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td id="Id">
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4"><span class="">Text data: </span></div>
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-5 col-xs-8"><span class="">Text Data</span><span class="">Text data</span></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><span class="">Text data</span></div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-9">
        <button class="btn button-offset" ng-click="editData()" id="editDataBtn_1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
        <button class="btn button-offset hide" ng-click="saveData()" id="saveDataBtn_1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span></button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="Id_1">
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4"><span class="">Text data: </span></div>
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-5 col-xs-8"><span class="">Text Data</span><span class="">Text data</span><</div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><span class="">Text data</span></div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-9">
        <button class="btn button-offset" ng-click="editData()" id="editDataBtn_2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
        <button class="btn button-offset hide" ng-click="saveData()" id="saveDataBtn_2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span></button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please refer the following images for the output difference:

Before resizing (resolution > 768px)

[image]

After resizing (resolution < 768px)

[image]

Please excuse the watermark :)

Comment: If you observe in image 2; After resizing (resolution < 768px), you can see the 'Asset' table is been joined with the 'Paricipation' table and so on. Though each one is different table.

Answer (score 0):

In css add margin-bottom to table only for width < 768px:

```
.table{
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
       margin-bottom: 20px!important;
    }
}
```

Comment: above solution increase the spacing but he border to left and right still connect two tables.

Comment: Remove the border for table:
`@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
.table{
       border: none!important;
    }
}`

Then if needed customize the border for thead and tbody:
`@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
.table thead{
       *some css *
    }
}`
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
`.table tbody{
       *some css *
    }
}`